# Frequent Popups while working on Classic UI for Sites 9.5

Tags: sites-9.5, access-management

Frequent Popups while working on Classic UI for Sites 9.5. Tridion Sites 9.5 is set up to use SAML IDP in access management.

Some of the details are as follows:

1. The popup appears every 1 min and closes automatically without the need for any input.
2. Popup frequency reduces for a small duration of time after an IISRESET on the Content Manager server.
3. AccessTokeLifetime in Access management settings is set to a default of 3600s.
4. OIDC_Auth is getting a new value with every popup.

The issue appears to be similar to  https://gateway.sdl.com/apex/communityknowledge?articleName=000011500

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: What is SAML Idp provider did you use? 
In the mentioned gateway articles provided HF for Tridion Sites 9.0 and 9.1 direct integration with SAML 2.0. better I would advise raising a support ticket to RWS/fSDL Support.

Comment: Your Tridion Sites and Access Management, Is it running on the same server? make sure both servers are using the same timezone

Comment: Yes, Tridion Sites and Access management are running on same servers. 

We are using SAML with Siteminder.

Comment: Anything noteworthy in Tridion Event Log and/or Access Management log file? If not, try changing the Log level. It may also help to just observe the requests sent by the browser (using F12 or a debugging proxy like Fiddler).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RWS team provided access management hotfix "AccessManagement_1.0.0.25543" which resolved the issue.

Comment: Can you please accept your own answer to close this?